# how to select distinct value by boolean condition in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i want to select distinct column value, group by another column condition(equal or not), table for example:

```
column  A, B
1, blue
2, blue
3, yellow
```

sql like:

```
select distinct(A), B=='blue' as `is_blue` group by `is_blue`
```

expected result:

```
1, True
2, True
3, False
```

using sqlalchemy twice:

```
session.query(Table.A).filter(Table.B == 'blue').distinct(Table.A)
session.query(Table.A).filter(Table.B != 'blue').distinct(Table.A)
```

but how to query it once?

Comment: What is grouped in your expected result?

Comment: column B == 'blue' or not

Comment: If your dataset is grouped by a boolean value, you can't have more than two rows, as all rows collapse into the true row and the false row. So your expected output is not really the expected output.

Comment: I dont think sqlalchemy will let you create calculated columns ...

Comment: I think i found the solution: ```crit_d = (Table.B == 'blue')
res = session.query(Table.A, crit_d.label('is_default')).distinct(tables.Records.type, crit_d)
for r in res:
 print(r.type, r.is_default)```  is it efficient?

Comment: lol that was easy now i just feel silly :P

Answer (score 0):

self answering, is it correct and efficient?

```
crit_d = (Table.B == 'blue') 
res = session.query(Table.A, crit_d.label('is_default')).distinct(
    tables.Records.type, crit_d) 
for r in res: 
    print(r.type, r.is_default)
```